# Keycloak - Get email address from Identity Provider Login without creating a new account

Tags: javascript, openshift, openid, keycloak, openshift-origin

I'm trying to use Google as an Identity Provider for Keycloak as an OAuth provider for OpenShift.

The default authentication flow for the first-broker-login allows any Google account to gain access to Keycloak, so I want to insert a script as early as possible in the Authentication Flow to validate that the email being used by the user belongs to a specific Hosted Domain.

My current script looks like this:

```
AuthenticationFlowError = Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowError");

function authenticate(context) {

    var username = user ? user.username : "anonymous";
    LOG.info(script.name + " trace auth for: " + username);

    var authShouldPass = typeof user.email !== 'undefined' && user.email.endsWith("domain.com");
    if (!authShouldPass) {

        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
        return;
    }

    context.success();
}
```

Using this script before the "Create User If Unique" authentication step will error out because the UserModel doesn't exist, because no user exists at this point of the flow in this context.

Moving this to a later stage in the flow (After `Create User If Unique`) allows a user to be created in the flow context and the script succeeds in detecting the rogue email, however, a rogue user now has access to Keycloak (unless I add a `user.setEnabled(false);` in the if statement).

I've been bashing my head against this for several days now and I am at a loss.

[Screenshot of Authentication Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGc02.png)

**Edit:** I've tried modifying the script to bypass the non-existent `UserModel` by using statements such as `var email = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("email");` - which just returns `null`

**Edit 2:** When logging in, the email address that I attempt to use is in the error logs:

```
07:11:34,374 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-5) \
type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_FIRST_LOGIN_ERROR, \
realmId=openshift, clientId=account, \
userId=null, ipAddress=10.131.0.1, \
error=user_not_found, identity_provider=google, \
auth_method=openid-connect, redirect_uri=https://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/openshift/account/login-redirect, \
identity_provider_identity=user@domain.com, code_id=code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging with a coworker, we discovered the solution.

The last line of the Error Log prints out a whole bunch of variables, one of which is `identity_provider_identity=user@domain.com`, after digging we traced this through to the `EventBuilder` class and then into the `Event` class.
In the `Event` class is a method that calls a hashmap named `details`.

```
public Event clone() {
    Event clone = new Event();
    clone.time = time;
    clone.type = type;
    clone.realmId = realmId;
    clone.clientId = clientId;
    clone.userId = userId;
    clone.sessionId = sessionId;
    clone.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    clone.error = error;
    clone.details = details != null ? new HashMap<>(details) : null;
    return clone;
}
```

`context.getEvent().event.details.get("identity_provider_identity")` will return the email being used by the client.